# "I Like It" and "Tags & Notes" missing in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata-service, social-tag

Here is my scenario,

I have two farms (FARM A and FARM B). When I browse the site from FARM A everything looks good and I can see "I Like It" and "Tags & Notes" but when I browse the site from FARM B I do not see "I Like It" and "Tags & Notes".

I have followed below article in order to see how to activate this feature. This article is all about disabling so I just checked if any of those settings are disabled on FARM B and everything looks good.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/disable-i-like-it-tags-notes-in-sharepoint-2010.html

On top of this, I am also seeing another issue where when I add "Note Board" web part it looks blank and only title is visible on FARM B. "Note Board" web part works file on FARM A.

Comment: are both farm using the same MMS service? what about the UPA...do you have one UPA consumed by both farm or ?

Comment: Yes both Farm is using same MMS and UPA.

Comment: Did you build the trust between farm, & publish the upa from publishing farm n consume it in 2nd farm? Same thing with MMS?

Comment: I think the farm not showing the tags n notes, is ur consuming farm....in that farm go to central admin, application management..manage services application....here cluck on the MMS which is from publishing farm and check the properties and make sure tag n notes option is selected here.